# Crear un array en una clase PHP

Tags: php

Buenas, tengo que realizar el siguiente ejercicio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo hecho lo siguiente

```
class Jugador {

    private $numeroJug;
    private $ptos;

    function __construct($numeroJug) {
        $this->numeroJug = $numeroJug;
    }

function getNumeroJug() {
    return $this->numeroJug;
}

 function getPtos() {
    return $this->ptos;
}

function addPuntos($ptos){

    $sumaPtos=0;

    if($ptos>0){

        $ptos+=$sumaPtos;

    }
    return $sumaPtos;

}


}

class Equipo{


}
```

Tengo dudas en cuanto a lo hecho en el método addPtos de si sería así y sobretodo no sé como se introduciría el array jugadores de tipo jugador en la clase Equipo.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Las imágenes pueden ser difíciles de leer (pensemos en celulares que no definan bien la imagen o en personas con problemas de vista). ¿Podrías por favor incluir el mensaje como texto? Encontrarás el enlace para **[edit]** debajo de tu pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo esta respuesta hecho rápido.

Quizá falten algunos controles en la clase, pero viendo que era un ejercicio tampoco quise meterme con cosas muy avanzadas.

### Clase `Jugador`

En el método `addPuntos` había un error de diseño. Un método de agregar no debería devolver nada. Para conocer el estado del objeto usa un `getter` La finalidad del método es agregar puntos al objeto, no devolver los puntos que tiene, para eso existe el método `getPuntos()`.

```
class Jugador {

    private $numeroJug;
    private $ptos; 

    function __construct($numeroJug) {
        $this->numeroJug = $numeroJug;
    }

    function getNumeroJug() {
        return $this->numeroJug;
    }

     function getPtos() {
        return $this->ptos;
    }

    function addPuntos($ptos){
        if($ptos>0){
            $this->ptos+=$ptos;
        }
    //    return $sumaPtos; ERROR DE DISEÑO
    }
}
```

---

### Clase `Equipo`

Básicamente sería esto:

Tendría una propiedad llamada `$jugador` del tipo `array`, que guardaría un array de objetos `Jugador` pasados a través del método `addJugador()`.

El método `getTotal()` calcula el total de puntos de todos los jugadores, obteniéndolos y sumándolos mediante el método `getPuntos`  del objeto `Jugador`.

También se puede verificar que el parámetro pasado al método es del tipo `Jugador` usando `instanceof`... De esa manera se evita que el método reciba cualquier cosa.

Hay más controles avanzados que se pueden usar, pero ese dependerá ya de ti y de los requerimientos que tengas.

```
class Equipo{
    private  $jugador=array();

    function __construct() {
        
    }
    
    function addJugador($unJugador){
        if ($unJugador instanceof Jugador) {
            $this->jugador[]=$unJugador;
        }
    }
    
    function getTotal(){
        $total=0;
        foreach($this->jugador as $arr) {
            $total+=$arr->getPtos();
        }
        return $total;
    }
    
}
```

---

### Código de prueba

<kbd>**[VER DEMO COMPLETO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/SATFQ10500)**</kbd>

Vamos a probar nuestro código.

```
/*Código de prueba*/

$unJugador=new Jugador(1);
$otroJugador=new Jugador(7);
$unJugador->addPuntos(50);
$unJugador->addPuntos(3);
$otroJugador->addPuntos(27);
    
$elEquipo=new Equipo();
$elEquipo->addJugador($unJugador);
$elEquipo->addJugador($otroJugador); 

$totalPuntos=$elEquipo->getTotal();
echo "Total de puntos: ".$totalPuntos;
echo PHP_EOL;

/*Viendo un Jugador por dentro*/
var_dump($unJugador);

/*Viendo el Equipo por dentro*/
var_dump($elEquipo);
```

**Salida:**

Para el total de puntos:

```
Total de puntos: 80
```

Objeto `Jugador`:

```
object(Jugador)#1 (2) {
  ["numeroJug":"Jugador":private]=>
  int(1)
  ["ptos":"Jugador":private]=>
  int(53)
}
```

Objeto `Equipo`:

```
object(Equipo)#3 (1) {
  ["jugador":"Equipo":private]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(Jugador)#1 (2) {
      ["numeroJug":"Jugador":private]=>
      int(1)
      ["ptos":"Jugador":private]=>
      int(53)
    }
    [1]=>
    object(Jugador)#2 (2) {
      ["numeroJug":"Jugador":private]=>
      int(7)
      ["ptos":"Jugador":private]=>
      int(27)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, perfectamente explicado :)

Comment: Amigo, también me surge la duda cuando el ejercicio dice "Se crearán 9 jugadores mediante un bucle for" y "El numero de dorsal de cada jugador será consecutivo", ¿cómo se crearían 9 jugadores con un bucle for?     Yo he intenado asi pero entonces todos tendrían el mismo nombre no?                            
          for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
            $jugador = new Jugador($i);
        }

Comment: @FelipeJiménezPrieto eso es muy fácil. Creas una instancia de la clase `Equipo`. Luego abres un bucle `for` del 1 al 9 y dentro del bucle creas en cada iteracción un objeto `Jugador` asignando en el constructor el número equivalente a `$i`. Al mismo tiempo usas `rand` para asignar los puntos aleatorios y finalmente agregas el objeto `Jugador` a la instancia de la clase `Equipo` que acabas de crear. Y calculas el total de puntos como ya se ha indicado...

Comment: ...sería algo así más o menos: **`$elEquipo=new Equipo();

for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
    $unJugador=new Jugador($i);
    $puntosAleatorio=rand(20,100);
    $unJugador->addPuntos($puntosAleatorio);
    $elEquipo->addJugador($unJugador);    
}`**  Sugiero que leas sobre `rand` y sobre `for` en el Manual de PHP. Saludos.