# Calcular asistencias, faltas, retardos en PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, php5

Quiero calcular las asistencias, faltas y retardos de TODOS los empleados que retorne la función `buscarEmpleados()`
a partir de una fecha A y una Fecha B las cuales son recibidas en `$dates1` y `$dates2`

`buscarEmpleados` me retorna una lista de`NoEmpleados` o `idClaves`

la idclave que me retorne quiero enviarla como parametro a otras funciones por ejemplo a: `consultarFecha($empleado,$tdate);` 
tengo definido un foreach que recorre `buscarEmpleados()` para traer los `NoEmpleados`, sin embargo no lo esta haciendo de la 
manera correcta, ya que en mi tabla solo me trae un solo `NoEmpleado` y no hace los cálculos correspondientes.

El código funciona cuando es un solo `NoEmpleado`, pero no lo he logrado hacer con mas de 1

*Código para calcular con todos los empleados:*

```
public $idclave;
public $fktipo;


public function buscarEmpleados()
    {


    $res = array("idclave"=>"","FechaIng"=>"");
    $i = 0;

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($this->conn,"select * FROM tblpersonal ");

    if( $stmt === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }



    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {


       //$res[$i] = $row['idClave'];


        $this->idclave = $row['idClave'];
        $this->tipo = $row['fkTipo'];

       $i++;


    }


    sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);

     return $res;

    }
```

*Código para el calculo de retardos, faltas etc.:*

```
<?php

$dates1 = strtotime($_POST['date1']); 
$dates2 = strtotime($_POST['date2']);   
$turno = array();


$horas = 0;
$festivo = false;
$festlab = 0; 

$datediff = $dates2 - $dates1;
$datedifdays = ($datediff/(60*60*24));
$descanso = 0;
$asistencias = 0;
$faltas = 0;
$horasextra = 0;
$festivotrabajado = 0;
$retardos = 0;
$diff_in_min = 0;
$deslab = 0;
$tolerancia = 0;
$permisos = 0;





include("horarios.php");
$numemp = array();



$numemp = $emp->buscarEmpleados();


foreach ($numemp as $empleado) {


    switch($emp->tipo)
{

    case 8:
    $tolerancia = -10;
    break;

    case 9:
    $tolerancia = -6;
    break;

    case 10:
    $tolerancia = -10;
    break;
}




    $val1 = $emp->idclave; ///Me retorna el NoEmpleado
    $val2 = $emp->tipo; ///Me retorna el tipo

    echo "Soy clave1",$val1; //Impresión
    echo "Soy clave2",$val2; //Impresión

    for ($i=0;$i<=$datedifdays;$i++){

    $date = new DateTime($_POST['date1']);
    $date->modify('+'.$i.' day');
    $dia = $date->format('l');




    if (in_array($dia,$turno))
    {



        $tdate = date_format($date, 'd-m-Y') . ' '; 
        $tdate = trim($tdate);  

        $arr = $db->consultarFecha($empleado,$tdate);

        $entrada = $arr["fechaEntrada"];
        $salida =  $arr["fechaSalida"];     

        $fest = array();
        $fest = $db->consultarFestivo($tdate);

        if ($fest["observacion"] != "")
        {
            $festivo = true;

        }else{
            $festivo = false;
        }


        $entr = new DateTime($entrada); 

            //retardo

        if ($entrada  == "" )
        {


            $permiso = array();
            $permiso = $db->consultarPermiso($empleado,$tdate);

            if($permiso["razon"] != "")
            {

                $permiso++;

            }else
            {

                if($festivo == false) 
                {
                    $faltas++;
                }


            }

        }


        if ($entrada != "" )        

        {

            $entrada1 = $entrada;
            $horaentrada = $date->format('d-m-Y') . " " . $ent; 
            $diffe = strtotime($horaentrada) - strtotime($entrada1);
            $diff_in_min = $diffe/60;               

            if($festivo == true) 
            {
                $festlab++;
            }


            $diff = strtotime($salida) - strtotime($entrada);
            $diff_in_hrs = $diff/3600;


        // calculamos sumario           

            $asistencias++;

            if (round($diff_in_hrs)  > $horas)
            {
                $horasextra +=  (round($diff_in_hrs)  - $horas );
            }


            if (round($diff_in_min)  < $tolerancia)
            {
                $retardos++;
            }

        }else
        {

        $tdate = date_format($date, 'd-m-Y'); 
        $tdate = trim($tdate);  
        $arr = $db->consultarFecha($empleado,$tdate);
        $entrada = $arr["fechaEntrada"];
        $salida =  $arr["fechaSalida"];         
        $entr = new DateTime($entrada); 


        if ($entrada != "" )        

        {

            $deslab++;

            $entrada1 = $entrada;
            $horaentrada = $date->format('d-m-Y') . " " . $ent; 
            $diffe = strtotime($horaentrada) - strtotime($entrada1);
            $diff_in_min = $diffe/60;               


            $diff = strtotime($salida) - strtotime($entrada);
            $diff_in_hrs = $diff/3600;

            if (round($diff_in_hrs)  > $horas)
            {
                $horasextra +=  (round($diff_in_hrs)  - $horas );
            }


            if (round($diff_in_min)  < $tolerancia)
            {

         // $retardos++;

            }

        }
        //echo "Descanso <br />";
        $descanso++;

    }
}


} 

?>
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th>Empleado</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Puesto</th>
            <th>Tipo</th>
            <th>Turno</th>
            <th>Supervisor</th>
            <th>Asistencia</th>
            <td>Faltas</td>
            <td>Retardos </td>
            <!--
            <th>Información </th>
            -->
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr class="success">
            <td><?php  echo $empleado; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $asistencias; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $faltas; ?></td>

            <td><?php echo $retardos; ?></td>

        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

<?php

}


?>
```

*Código para calcular con un solo empleado:*

*Funcion buscando un NoEMpleado en especifico*

```
public function buscarId($empno)
{

    $res = array();


         $stmt = sqlsrv_query($this->conn,"select p.*,e.Descripcion as Tipo,de.* from tblpersonal  
        JOIN tbldescanso de on p.idClave = de.idclave WHERE p.idclave ='". $empno."'  ");

    if( $stmt === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }

    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

    //General information 

        $this->idclave = $row['idClave'];
        $this->fktipo = $row['fkTipo'];




    }

    sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
}


<?php

$db = new database();
$emp = new empleado();

$dates1 = strtotime($_POST['date1']);  // Obtenemos las dos Fechas
$dates2 = strtotime($_POST['date2']);   
$turno = array();

$empl = $_REQUEST['empno'];// Dato desde un campo de texto
$horas = 0;
$festivo = false;
$festlab = 0; 

$datediff = $dates2 - $dates1;
$datedifdays = ($datediff/(60*60*24));
$descanso = 0;
$asistencias = 0;
$faltas = 0;
$horasextra = 0;
$festivotrabajado = 0;
$retardos = 0;
$diff_in_min = 0;
$deslab = 0;
$tolerancia = 0;
$permisos = 0;

//** Obtenemos los datos del empleado 
$emp->buscarId($empl);

$nombre = $emp->nombre;
$idturno = $emp->idturno;
$puesto = "";
$evento = "";




switch($emp->tipo)
{

    case 8:
    $tolerancia = -10;
    break;

    case 9:
    $tolerancia = -6;
    break;

    case 10:
    $tolerancia = -10;
    break;


}

//Configuramos detalles turno, horario y horas trabajadas
//Carga configuración de horarios 



include("horarios.php");


for ($i=0;$i<=$datedifdays;$i++)
{

    $date = new DateTime($_POST['date1']);
    $date->modify('+'.$i.' day');
    $dia = $date->format('l');



    if (in_array($dia,$turno))
    {

        $tdate = date_format($date, 'd-m-Y') . ' '; 
        $tdate = trim($tdate);  

        $arr = $db->consultarFecha($empl,$tdate);

        $entrada = $arr["fechaEntrada"];
        $salida =  $arr["fechaSalida"];     

        $fest = array();
        $fest = $db->consultarFestivo($tdate);

        if ($fest["observacion"] != "")
        {
            $festivo = true;

        }else{
            $festivo = false;
        }


        $entr = new DateTime($entrada); 

            //retardo

        if ($entrada  == "" )
        {


            $permiso = array();
            $permiso = $db->consultarPermiso($empl,$tdate);

            if($permiso["razon"] != "")
            {

                $permiso++;

            }else
            {

                if($festivo == false) 
                {
                    $faltas++;
                }


            }

        }


        if ($entrada != "" )        

        {

            $entrada1 = $entrada;
            $horaentrada = $date->format('d-m-Y') . " " . $ent; 
            $diffe = strtotime($horaentrada) - strtotime($entrada1);
            $diff_in_min = $diffe/60;               

            if($festivo == true) 
            {
                $festlab++;
            }


            $diff = strtotime($salida) - strtotime($entrada);
            $diff_in_hrs = $diff/3600;



            $asistencias++;

            if (round($diff_in_hrs)  > $horas)
            {
                $horasextra +=  (round($diff_in_hrs)  - $horas );
            }


            if (round($diff_in_min)  < $tolerancia)
            {
                $retardos++;
            }

        }else
        {

        $tdate = date_format($date, 'd-m-Y');
        $tdate = trim($tdate);  
        $arr = $db->consultarFecha($empl,$tdate);
        $entrada = $arr["fechaEntrada"];
        $salida =  $arr["fechaSalida"];         
        $entr = new DateTime($entrada); 


        if ($entrada != "" )        

        {

            $deslab++;

            $entrada1 = $entrada;
            $horaentrada = $date->format('d-m-Y') . " " . $ent; 
            $diffe = strtotime($horaentrada) - strtotime($entrada1);
            $diff_in_min = $diffe/60;               


            $diff = strtotime($salida) - strtotime($entrada);
            $diff_in_hrs = $diff/3600;

            if (round($diff_in_hrs)  > $horas)
            {
                $horasextra +=  (round($diff_in_hrs)  - $horas );
            }


            if (round($diff_in_min)  < $tolerancia)
            {


            }

        }
        $descanso++;

    }
}

}

?>              
<p>Fecha de Inicio: <?php echo $_POST['date1'];  ?>   </p>       
<p>Fecha final:  <?php echo $_POST['date2'];  ?>    </p>       



<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Empleado</th>
            <th>asistencia</th>
            <th>faltas</th>
            <th>retardo </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr class="success">
            <td><?php echo $empleado; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $asistencias; ?></td>

            <td><?php echo $faltas; ?></td>

            <td><?php echo $retardos; ?></td>

        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: En donde declaras las variables $this->idclave y $this->tipo?

Comment: @alanfcm ya edite el código, estan declaradas dentro de mi clase como variables publicas.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema esta aqui:

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

   //$res[$i] = $row['idClave'];

    $this->idclave = $row['idClave'];
    $this->tipo = $row['fkTipo'];

   $i++;

}
```

Las variables idclave y tipo solo pueden sostener un valor y cada vez que el loop itera las sobreescribe.  Las variables deberian de ser arrays para guardar multiples valores.

Comment: Arriba del While esta añadido un Array: $res = array("idclave"=>"","FechaIng"=>"");

Comment: Cambia esta linea: $val1 = $emp->idclave; por $val1 = $empleado->idclave.  Y lo mismo para $val2

Answer (score 0):

Dado que, como parece indicar tu código, donde está la función `buscarEmpleados` es una `Clase`, lo lógico sería que dicha clase tuviese un atributo que sea un array, y que sea en ese array donde guardes los diferentes valores organizados.

Es más, esa clase podría manejar un array de objetos del tipo `Empleado`, donde se mapeen los resultados obtenidos de la base de datos. Eso sería lo más lógico. Pero no nos metamos en eso ahora. Tratemos de resolver el problema y si te interesa, lee mi último comentario dentro del código...

Por lo pronto, podríamos resolverlo con algo así (he comentado las líneas en tu código original que considero innecesarias):

```
//public $idclave;
//public $fktipo;
/*
    *Declaras un miembro en la clase que será el array final con los resultados
    *Lo declaras como private, para respetar la encapsulación, o sea, que el array
    *no pueda modificarse desde fuera de la clase
    *Esta misma función haría las veces de getter, en este caso concreto
    *retornando una representación completa del array
*/
private  $arrEmpleados=array();

public function buscarEmpleados()
    {


    //$res = array("idclave"=>"","FechaIng"=>""); Esto vendría a ser un miembro de la clase
    //$i = 0; Esto no es necesario

    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($this->conn,"select * FROM tblpersonal ");

    if( $stmt === false) {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
    }

    while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

       /*
            *Nótese que aquí, las claves del array serán los nombres de cada columna
            *en tu código dabas otro nombre a las claves... no sé por qué
            *de todos modos, puedes hacerlo, modificando la línea de más abajo
            *pero sería algo ilógico...
            *Nótese que esto tiene MUCHA IMPORTANCIA, A LA HORA DE LEER EL ARRAY
        */
        $this->arrEmpleados[]=$row;
    }

    sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);

     /*Aquí estarías retornando un array con cada resultado encontrado*/
     return $this->arrEmpleados;

    }
```

---

**LUEGO**, el código donde usas el método, tendría que ser modificado ligeramente:

```
include("horarios.php");
//$numemp = array(); No hace falta... me permitiré también usar un nombre más descriptivo

$arrEmpleados = $emp->buscarEmpleados();
foreach ($arrEmpleados as $empleado) {

    /*
        *Aquí supongo que en tblpersonal hay un columna llamada tipo
        *dado que la función retornó un array propiamente dicho
        *lo leemos como tal $empleado["tipo"], 
        *y no como una propiedad de la clase usando $emp["tipo"]
        *esto demuestra un claro error de diseño en tu código
    */

    /*
        *Más abajo, volvías a recuperar este valor en la variable $val2
        *así que la definimos aquí una sola vez y listo...
    */

    $tipo=$empleado["tipo"];
    switch($tipo)
    {

        case 8:
        $tolerancia = -10;
        break;

        case 9:
        $tolerancia = -6;
        break;

        case 10:
        $tolerancia = -10;
        break;
    }   

    /*
        *Como ya comenté más arriba, aquí suponemos que también en tblpersonal
        *hay una columna llamada idclave y otra llamada tipo
        *En una futura evolución de tu código, si quieres tenerlo más organizado
        *quizá convenga tener una clase que represente a los empleados, y llenar 
        *un array de objetos Empleado con sus propiedades
        *en mi respuesta a esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/134253/29967
        *puedes ver un ejemplo de lo que digo
    */

    $val1 = $empleado["idclave"]; ///Me retorna el NoEmpleado
    //$val2 = $empleado["tipo"]; ///Me retorna el tipo

    echo "Soy clave1 ",$val1; //Impresión
    echo "Soy clave2 ",$tipo; //Impresión

    for ($i=0;$i<=$datedifdays;$i++){

    $date = new DateTime($_POST['date1']);
    $date->modify('+'.$i.' day');
    $dia = $date->format('l');

//resto del código
//cierre del foreach
```