# Asignar objeto a otro objeto en php

Tags: php, poo

Tengo el siguiente código donde hay dos clases 'jugador' y 'equipo', las dos clases ya tienen 3 objetos creados por defecto cada uno.

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es **asignar un jugador a un equipo**, pero no estoy seguro de cómo hacerlo.

Estas son las clases :

**team.php**

```
<?php session_start();

class Team {

    private $teams;
    private $name;

    public function __construct($name){

        $this->name = $name;
        $this->teams = array();
    }

    public function getName(){
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function addTeam($oneTeam){
        $this->teams[] = $oneTeam;

        return $this;
    }

    public function printTeams(){

        echo "<br>"."<br>";
        echo "<b>Teams available</b>";
        echo "<br>"."<br>";

        foreach($this->$teams as $team){

            echo $team->getName() . " ";
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }

}


// Load the team data of the session and if it does not exist create a new team.
function loadDataTeam(){
    return isset($_SESSION['team']) ? $_SESSION['team'] : new Team();
}

// Save the team data in the session.
function saveDataTeam($team){
    $_SESSION['team'] = $team;
}

$team = new Materia();

//teams by default.
$team->addTeam(new Team("Team 1"));
$team->addTeam(new Team("Team 2"));
$team->addTeam(new Team("Team 3"));

saveDataTeam($team);

?>
```

**player.php**

```
<?php session_start();
    include_once("team.php");
    class Player {
        private $players;
        private $name;
        public function __construct($name){
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->players = array();
        }
        public function getName(){
            return $this->name;
        }
        public function addPlayer($onePlayer){
            $this->players[] = $onePlayer;
            return $this;
        }
        public function printPlayers(){
            foreach($this->players as $player){
                echo $player->getName() . " ";
                echo "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
    // Load the player data of the session and if it does not exist create a new player.
    function loadDataPlayer(){
        return isset($_SESSION['player']) ? $_SESSION['player'] : new Player();
    }
    // Save the player data in the session.
    function saveDataPlayer($player){
        $_SESSION['player'] = $player;
    }
    $player = new Player();
    //Players by default.
    $player->addPlayer(new Player("Player 1"));
    $player->addPlayer(new Player("Player 2"));
    $player->addPlayer(new Player("Player 3"));
    saveDataPlayer($player);
    ?>
```

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Asignar jugador a equipo</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>

    <?php

    form();

    include_once("team.php");
    include_once("player.php");

    $player = new Player();
    $team = new Team();

    $player = loadDataPlayer();
    $team = loadDataTeam();

    function form(){

        echo '<FORM METHOD="POST" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 73px;">
        <h2>Asignar jugador a equipo</h2>
        <label>Introduce el nombre del jugador : </label><INPUT class="form" TYPE = "text" NAME = "name"> <br>
        <label>Introduce el nombre del equipo : </label><INPUT class="form" TYPE = "text" NAME = "team"> <br><br>
        <INPUT class="form" TYPE = "submit" VALUE = "Send" name="action">
        </ FORM>';
    }

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Creo que estás planteando mal tu código. Si lo piensas como en la realidad, sabrás que un `Team` agrupa a varios objetos del tipo `Player`, por tanto, para expresar eso lo lógica sería tener en `Team` un array que guarde objetos del tipo `Player`, luego, mediante un método `addPlayer` **en la clase `Team`** agregas cada objeto `Player` al array de jugadores. [Aquí hay un ejemplo muy parecido a lo que buscas hacer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/134267/29967). Piénsalo como en la realidad y verás que es super fácil planterar correctamente el modelo de datos. Saludos.